# Unable to cast the type 'Claim' to type 'ClaimDetail'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a problem with an EF6 and LINQ to Entities method inasmuch as I cannot cast from one class, `Claim`, to a derived class, `ClaimDetail`. I am certain that this cast would be valid but I don't know fiddle with the syntax to get the cast to work.

The relevant portions of the model look like this:

```
// Claim.cs
public class Claim
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ..other properties
}
```

and

```
// ClaimDetail.cs
public class ClaimDetail : Claim
{
    public string ClaimRef { get; set; }
    // ..other properties
}
```

I have another class, `Request`, that looks like this:

```
// Request.cs
public class Request
{
    public Claim Claim { get; set; }
    // ..other properties
}
```

These classes form a part of the context, like this:

```
// Context.cs
public DbSet<ClaimDetail> Claims { get; set; }
public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
```

Now, I would like to sort a LINQ query of `Request`s based on a property of `ClaimDetail`. I have this:

```
sorted = intermediate.OrderBy(r => ((ClaimDetail)r.Claim).ClaimRef);
```

where `intermediate` is an `IQueryable<Request>`. However, on trying to materialize this query, I receive the following message:

```
Unable to cast the type 'Claim' to type 'ClaimDetail'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

How can I do this, without resorting to calling `ToList()` on the intermediate results? That would be far too expensive.

Comment: Your *certain that this cast would be valid* is incorrect. You cannot cast an ancestor to a descendant; you can cast a descendant to an ancestor. Think about it logically: You can cast a Dog to an Animal, because there is a certainty that a Dog is an Animal. You cannot blindly cast an Animal to a Dog, because that animal might be a Horse or a Cow or a Cat. Trust me: Dogs hate it when you turn them into Cats.

Comment: Yes, I understand that much. What I meant is that within my code, I can be certain that in this situation, the `Claim`s are all `ClaimDetail`s. If I were performing this cast with the same data in C#, I could guarantee it would succeed is all I meant. Doing this type of casting is possible in C#, so why can EF not perform this cast in the SQL it generates?